# Error "cannot read property of value null" when trying to use bcrypt.compare

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use `bcrypt.compare` on my admin login route but I am getting "cannot read property of value null"

This is my password page:

```js
let passwordObject = await Password.findOne({
 subjectType: 1,
 status: 1,
 subjectId: adminId,
});
console.log('passowrd', passwordObject )
let data = await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordObject.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to `bcript.compare`. `passwordObject` is returning `null`, so you shouldn't try to access to its `value` property. You should check if `passwordObject` has value before trying to access to any of its supposed properties:

```js
let data = passwordObject && passwordObject.value ? await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordObject.value) : false;
```

Comment: how can i check if the passObject has value and also can you give me some examples thanks am new to bcrypt

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the problem is not related to `bcrypt` at all, it is a javascript problem. I have just added an example which checks if there is a password value before even calling to `bcrypt`, and assigns a `false` value to `data` in case there is no password value.